# Merging specific specific strings in character vector

Tags: r, vector

I have character vector where each level is a word. It has been generated from a text in which some segments are marked up with angular brackets. These segments vary in length. I need the marked up segments to be merged in the vector.

The input looks like this:

```
c("This","is","some","text","with","<marked","up","chunks>[L]","in","it")
```

I need the output to look like this:

```
c("This","is","some","text","with","<marked up chunks>[L]","in","it")
```

Thanks.

Comment: There can be "nested" marked segments ? e.g. c("a","<b","<c","c>","b>") ? If so, what do you need to do ?

Comment: Can there be multiple chunks in one vector?

Comment: There are no nested markups, but there are multiple chunks in one vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an approach that also works with multiple chunks in a vector:

```
vec <- c("This","is","some","text","with","<marked","up","chunks>[L]","in","it")

from <- grep("<", vec)
to <- grep(">", vec)

idx <- mapply(seq, from, to, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)

new_strings <- sapply(idx, function(x) 
  paste(vec[x], collapse = " "))

replacement <- unlist(mapply(function(x, y) c(y, rep(NA, length(x) - 1)), 
                             idx, new_strings, SIMPLIFY = FALSE))

new_vec <- "attributes<-"(na.omit(replace(vec, unlist(idx), replacement)), NULL)


[1] "This"                  "is"                   
[3] "some"                  "text"                 
[5] "with"                  "<marked up chunks>[L]"
[7] "in"                    "it"
```